# Text wraps before growing to max-width

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with set `max-width` containing some text. The problem is that the div never grows to its `max-width` and the text always wraps.

CSS:

```
/*Container*/
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #12161AEE;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/*Text*/
.tooltip-subtitle {
    color: #EEEEEE;
    max-width: 350px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Where's the markup ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `text-align: justify;` to the subtitle CSS. This will spread the words across the width of the element.

```
.tooltip-subtitle {
    color: #EEEEEE;
    max-width: 350px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. I have narrowed down the problem and apparently, even though the tooltip div has position: absolute it won't get bigger than it's parent for some reason. Do you have any idea what may cause this?

Comment: It would help if you could post a full code example. I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do.